# How to code fastest for loop ? vectors, iterators, basic ? what is the best method?

Tags: optimization, loops, for-loop, iterator, iteration

Before I wasn't considering any speed issue during 3D graphics programming, but now I have to consider it seriously for real-time applications. In real-time, as well as offline I have to use a lots of loops, I used to write algorithms with basic for loop like this..

```
for (i=0; i<nb; i++){}
```

So when I rum my algorithm with above for loop well you can also consider nested loops too, I have to wait for 5-10 seconds to finish it, but when I see any professional software they have much faster way for the same algorithm, just in eye blink time the algorithm is finished. Not professional, but the simple example of MeshLab.

So what the meshlab is using, is iterators like below.

```
std::vector<int> pStorage;          
vector<int>::iterator it;
for (it = pStorage.begin(); it!=pStorage.end(); ++it){}
```

So, my question is, how and which for loop should I use for my algorithms for speeding up my application. Any suggestion?

I have been doing research on this topic since days, I found iterators are faster, but I have tried it, used it, I found no difference in speed, why ? 
3D graphics programming usually heavy for processing, But I have to find a fastest way to make my loops faster.

Thanks.

Comment: For starters, you're compiling with optimizations right? And then you're using the most appropriate algorithm, expressed in the most straightforward way? These two things get you 97% the way there. The loop itself should be negligible compared to what's inside of it.

Comment: I don't really think it's the looping mechanism itself. Have you profiled your code?

Comment: what are you looping through?  forgive the syntax, but sizeof(myObj) = i; for(count = 0; count<i*count;count++)  will get you a long way.  Seriously though, what are you looping through.  Are you using the C++ stl?  Are you using straight up C?(In which case, kudos to you sir, may you build the first time machine).  Ok, arrays in C/C++ are syntactic sugar for pointer arithmatic.  You NEED to know how big the stuff is you are iterating through to optimize it.  Once you understand this your question will be answered.

Comment: Using any not-totally-bullshit compiler, the difference is exactly zero in a release build. Eliminating O(n^2) or worse algorithms and respecting cache coherence is what you want to look at, not at how to write a loop. Both the choice of algorithm and having data in cache are things that make a "seconds versus instantly" kind of difference.

Comment: I was thinking that might be there would be an other method to count such a huge number, but i think there is not any other solution than the nested for loops for my algorithms. The best way is to save the data in the cache, or look up table, or compute at once for one run. I have solved my issue by using the ram memory, I compute the full data only once and save into the ram, then using it wherever I want. It is really boosting up my application speed. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: what if we are using a linked list instead array or vector? the current item in the list have a pointer to the next item..so it saves time on search the next item, no?

Comment: getting from the current item to the next in an array or vector is just a single addition, vs. dereference. in practice, the difference is probably very small, but advantage actually goes to the vector/array, not the linked list.